# Playing a dice game, where the winner is determined when the first 6 appears

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

I did a course on probability in undergrad, and I felt like brushing up on it by working out some problems a colleague gave me:

"Two siblings are playing a dice game, where the winner is determined when the first 6 appears"

1. What's the probability that the 1st sibling wins?
2. What is the mean number of rolls needed before a winner is determined? (1 turn consists of 2 dice rolls, assuming no one won in that turn)
3. Is is true that they could settle the game by flipping a fair coin instead of rolling the dice?
4. Suppose that k dice are now rolled simultaneously by each player on his turn, and now the
   ﬁrst player to obtain a total of k (or more) 6’s, accumulated over all his throws, wins the
   game. (For example, if k = 3, then player 1 will throw 3 dice, and keep track of any 6’s that
   show up. If player 1 did not get all 6’s then player 2 will do the same. Assuming that player
   1 gets another turn, he will again throw 3 dice, and any 6’s that show up will be added to
   his previous total.)
   Should you expect this game to run for fewer turns than the original game? Compute the expectation

#### My attempt

1. Let $X$ be a random variable indicating the probability of getting a six. Now, $X\sim Geo(m)$, where $m$ represents the number of failures. Then, $Pr[X=x]=(1-\frac{1}{6})^m\frac{1}{6}$.
2. Since the geometric distribution has an expectation of $\frac{1}{p}$, then the mean number of rolls will be 6
3. For a fair coin the probability of getting heads or tail would be $\frac{1}{2}$. By virtue of this the random variable, $Y$, representing this wouldn't be the same i.e $Pr[Y=y]=(1-\frac{1}{2})^m\frac{1}{2}$ and the expectations would also be different. Thus it is not true.
4. I'm a little clueless about this one. But I believe it should use the negative binomial distribution somewhere here

Answer (score 0):

For question 3: if you flip a coin 3 times and write the outcome in binary you get a number 0-7 uniform random.  Redo if you get a 0 or 7 else you have a die roll.

For question 1: do you want the probability he wins if he goes first? If yes then this is the probability first 6 is on an odd roll.